# How to get post image caption by index

Tags: php, posts

I have multiple images in WordPress post, each image has different caption.
I want to get the image caption by the image index, but I can't figure out how to print the caption.

Here is what I have tried:

```
//$index - index of the image (if index is 0, its first image)
function getImageCaption($postID, $index){
    $post_id = $postID;
    // get the post object
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    // get the post thumbnail ID
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    // we need just the content
    $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

    if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[$index])) {
        return $thumbnail_image[$index]->post_excerpt;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

How can I display image caption by index?

Comment: If you know the post ID you can use  `get_post` instead of `get_posts` and avoid needing to use an index

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm having multiple images in one post, so I need to index the image.. But I guess my syntax is wrong here and I can't figure out why..

Comment: Your `get_posts` call retrieves a single post, aka the post thumbnail, it's not retrieving the images in the post, and the caption is stored in the post content not on the attachment. To do what you want to do you need to parse the current posts content, not call `get_posts`

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, that helped me solve it.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer for others with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have used function to extract data inside figcaption tags, and $position is stand for the index of the current image.

```
  function getImageCaption($postID, $position){
        $post_id = $postID;
        // get the post object
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        // we need just the content
        $content = $post->post_content;
        // we need a expression to match things
        $regex = '/<figcaption>(.*)<\/figcaption>/';
        // we want all matches
        preg_match_all( $regex, $content, $matches );
        // reversing the matches array
        $matches = array_reverse($matches);
        // we've reversed the array, so index 0 returns the result
        foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
            return $value[$position];
        }
    }
```